# How to simplify this jquery tree traversal?

Tags: jquery, jquery-traversing

**HTML**

```
...
<a id="delete1" href="http://www.example.com">TEST</a>
<p>First</p>
<p>Second</p>
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
<div id="hidden-qsd">123</div>
...
```

**JS**

```
var id = $('#delete1').nextUntil("div[id^='hidden']").next().last().attr('id');
```

I'd like to get the id of the closest "div" starting with "hidden" located after the link "#delete1".
This previous code is working but I think there is a simpler way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#delete1').nextAll('[id^="hidden"]').attr('id')
```

`nextAll()` is enough

example jsbin: http://jsbin.com/usowej/3/edit

Note:  if you have more than one element whose id is starting with `hidden` just use

```
$('#delete1').nextAll('[id^="hidden"]:first').attr('id')
```

to retrieve just the first occurence, see http://jsbin.com/usowej/4/edit

Comment: Yes, it's simpler, thank you. However, "nextAll" don't stop after the first result : it reads the whole DOM after the delete link, to find all occurences. So, we can maybe find a more efficient solution.

Comment: well if you have more than one element whose id is starting with hidden just use `$('#delete1').nextAll('[id^="hidden"]:first').attr('id')` using `:first` pseudoclass

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nextAll(selector)` to get the next siblings after the element:

```
var id = $('#delete1').nextAll("div[id^='hidden']").prop('id');
```

http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/